# Find number then replace it with number+1 Google Sheet

Tags: regex, string, google-sheets, replace, integer

I have some a group of cells on Google sheets with the following text:

KelleshaParkAfterChoice1_36

KelleshaParkAfterChoice1_37

KelleshaParkAfterChoice1_38

KelleshaParkAfterChoice1_39

KelleshaParkAfterChoice1_40

KelleshaParkAfterChoice1_41

KelleshaParkAfterChoice1_42

Now what i want to do is replace the last 2 digits(36,37,38,etc..) with those digits+1 (37,38,39,etc..) e.g:

KelleshaParkAfterChoice1_37

KelleshaParkAfterChoice1_38

KelleshaParkAfterChoice1_39

KelleshaParkAfterChoice1_40

KelleshaParkAfterChoice1_41

KelleshaParkAfterChoice1_42

KelleshaParkAfterChoice1_43

Trying to learn how to do that i stumbled upon regular expressions and Regex, so i learned that i can capture the last numbers with "(?\d{2})", and then i can access the numbers with $1, what i didn't find how to do yet is to make operations with the captured numbers, anyone knows the solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following formula

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR((REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,".*_")
             &REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"(.*_)","")+1)))
```

[image]

*(Please alter ranges to your needs)*

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)
- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)